# Keeping libraries in Eclipse for another PC

Tags: eclipse, opencv

I am kinda new to Eclipse. I downloaded a library called OpenCV and followed this tutorial on how to set it up http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/java_eclipse/java_eclipse.html#java-eclipse

I never worked with external libraries before, only basic programming.

Afterwards, I deleted both the archive and the extracted folder, and Eclipse doesn't detect it anymore(because it detects the folder that I extracted, duh).

My question is if I want to transfer my project to another pc, do I have to install OpenCV on that pc before hand, or how can I transfer OpenCV aswell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to have OpenCV on any PC that will be running OpenCV apps.  Whether you just copy it over from an existing PC or re-install it, you'll need to reconfigure eclipse so it knows where the OpenCV native libs and Jars are before it can run your app.

My suggestion would be to just follow that guide again for your different PC.  If you ever get the point of wanting to deploy your opencv app to many PCs, then would be the time to gain a deeper knowledge of the minimum requirements on a PC to run OpenCV apps.

Comment: Thing is OpenCV has like 4GB, so it's not that easy to install everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much into the Java implementation of OpenCV. But I guess, copying the /build/java folder to another PC and selecting this path in Eclipse would setup OpenCV Workspace. The size of this folder will not be too large.